# How to correctly self join table with events data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with analytics events

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
    event_uuid uuid,
    name character varying,
    content_json json,
    occurred_at timestamp(6) without time zone,
    session_uuid uuid
)
and
name can be i('StartEvent', 'ProgressEvent', 'EndEvent')
insert into events (event_uuid, name, content_json, occurred_at, session_uuid) values
('ffffffdb-d4e4-4f82-aa05-581e287a58aa', 'StartEvent', '{"data":"1"}', '2024-01-01 10:00', '0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824982'),
('ffffffdb-d4e4-4f82-aa05-581e287a58ab', 'ProgressEvent', '{"data":"2"}', '2024-01-01 10:01', '0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824982'),
('ffffffdb-d4e4-4f82-aa05-581e287a58ac', 'EndEvent', '{"data":"3"}', '2024-01-01 10:02', '0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824982'),
('ffffffdb-d4e4-4f82-aa05-581e287a58ad', 'StartEvent', '{"data":"4"}', '2024-01-01 10:00', '0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824983'),
('ffffffdb-d4e4-4f82-aa05-581e287a58ae', 'ProgressEvent', '{"data":"5"}', '2024-01-01 10:01', '0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824983'),
('ffffffdb-d4e4-4f82-aa05-581e287a58af', 'EndEvent', '{"data":"6"}', '2024-01-01 10:02', '0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824983'),
```

I want to create query for further aggregation which will have these columns

```
(session_uuid, start_occurred_at, start_event_content->>'data', progress_event_content->>'data', end_event_occurred_at
```

I tried to use self join "events" with "events" with "events" like this

```
select 
e.session_uuid, e.occurred_at, e.content_json->>'data' 
e2.content_json->>'data',
e3.occurred_at
from
(select * from events where name = 'StartEvent') e 
    left join (select * from events where name = 'ProgressEvent') e2 on e.session_uuid = e2.session_uuid
    left join (select * from events where name = 'EndEvent') e3 on e.session_uuid = e3.session_uuid
```

And it works, but it works only within couple of days. Because table has a lot of data for each day and when I try to join multiple days I get too big joins.

Also events are mostly in one day and I don't need 100% accuracy. So sessions on the border of days can be ignored.

What is the proper way to solve this task and join tables?
I think about crosstab, but didn't try it yet, will it be much faster?

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using `group by` with no self joins. Please note the use of `filter` clause.

```sql
select session_uuid,
  max(occurred_at)           filter (where name='StartEvent') start_occurred_at,
  max(content_json->>'data') filter (where name='StartEvent') start_event_content,
  max(content_json->>'data') filter (where name='ProgressEvent') progress_event_content,
  max(occurred_at)           filter (where name='EndEvent') end_occurred_at
from events
group by session_uuid;
```

| session_uuid | start_occurred_at | start_event_content | progress_event_content | end_occurred_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824982 | 2024-01-01 10:00:00.0 | 1 | 2 | 2024-01-01 10:02:00.0 |
| 0991f2de-3ffb-4358-bc86-877167824983 | 2024-01-01 10:00:00.0 | 4 | 5 | 2024-01-01 10:02:00.0 |

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQQC7VhUZNcPdXodHKFaCR/0)

Comment: it's awesome, works much faster, thank you!